# Why this C program gives o/p in windows not in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, windows

Here is a C program of type casting. It works in windows but not in linux. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int a = 30; 
  char b[10] = "hi";
  a=(char*)b;
  printf("%s",a);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you’re using 32-bit compilation on Windows and 64-bit on Linux .  The behaviour is undefined, so both responses are correct (well, permitted; neither is disallowed).

Comment: Please never say "not working" without indicating exactly in which way. In this case, I assume Segmentation fault; but in a larger program or a more complex question, we might not be able to guess.

Comment: Being pedantic, I think "neither is wrong" is more accurate than "both are correct".

Answer (score 0):

The better question is why it works at all: coincidence that `int` and `char*` both have the same size. You should never assume it, and should avoid spurious type assumptions and always use correct types.

On my Mac, `int` is 4 bytes, but `char*` is 8 bytes. Thus, putting 4 bytes on stack and popping 8 bytes off, then using that as an address, is the reason for Segmentation fault.

Comment: Since you don't actually state what you want to do, `printf("%s", b)` is a correct equivalent of your code. If you really need to convert a pointer to an integer and back, `size_t` is an integral type that is guaranteed to of appropriate size; don't use `int` for pointers.

Comment: You can't. C is strongly typed; integers are integers, and strings are strings (well, pointers to characters are pointers to characters). When you print an integer, you can't use `%s` in `printf`. Either have a variable that holds the _string_ `10`, which can get replaced by the string `"hello"`, or have a flag that determines whether you `printf("%d", numbervar)` or `printf("%s", stringvar)`. You cannot solve it with a typecast.

Comment: It wouldn't work. Take out `a=(char*)b` and note that what is printed is _not_ `30`. It is just not throwing an error; doesn't mean your logic is correct.

Comment: That's tough, but I still won't chat outside Stack Overflow. Anyway - please reread my comment. I know it prints `hi` for you, but it wouldn't print it `if you don't reassign` `a` from its original value of `30`. You expect it would print `30` if the value is unchanged. It would not. You need `print('%d', a)` to print `30`, not `printf("%s", a)`.

Comment: If you have another question, ask another question. There's many people besides me that will try to answer to their best ability. But please stop trying to get a contact outside Stack Overflow. It is inappropriate. While I am glad to answer your questions you post here, I am not your employee, and you do not have a claim on my time. I will not be contacting you at gmail.